# Is calling the superclass constructor in a subclass really important?

Tags: python, class, subclassing

The following piece of Python code uses a superclass solely as the repository of functions that one of more subclasses may draw from:

```
class Class(object):
    ''' A trivial repository for functions to be inherited '''

    def function(self):
        print self

class Subclass(Class):
    ''' A subclass where the action is'''

    def __init__(self):
        pass

subitem = Subclass()
subitem.function()
```

This seems to be the minimum amount of coding that fits that purpose.

However, I received a non-argued hint that a better way to code the same would be having a constructor in the superclass and calling it inside the subclass constructor (seemingly a sort of tighter coupling):

```
class Class(object):
    ''' The function repository, now featuring a constructor'''

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def function(self):
        print self


class Subclass(Class):
    ''' The same subclass, but its constructor invokes the superclass constructor'''

    def __init__(self):
        Class.__init__(self)

subitem = Subclass()
subitem.function()
```

The question is... In which way would the second way of subclassing be 'superior' to the first one? Superior might mean more general, applicable to a greater variety of situations and so forth.

Thanks for thinking along.

Comment: `seemingly a sort of tighter binding` -- If by that you mean "tighter coupling," classes that inherit from other classes are already tightly coupled.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Remark on word choice taken aboard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you add variables to `self` in the constructor of `Class` and don't call `Class.__init__()` in the constructor of `Subclass`, then these variables will not be in your `Subclass` object.

See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166473/5812729) for an example.

In your case, `Class` is simply a function repository. So, it will not make a difference. However, in the future, you may need to add some variables so the functions in that class will work together. Using `self` may be convenient for that purpose.

Adding `Class.__init__()` now may then save you some time if you choose to use `self` later. Indeed, it may take a long time to figure out that you have forgotten that line in the `Subclass` constructor.

Comment: In other words, functions in the super class are available automatically, but variables in the super class will not be available if it is not constructed explicitly, which is usually done in `super().__init__()`, but could also be done in subclass.